# Show Node in MvcSiteMapProvider if its action is marked with [Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nodes, authorize-attribute, mvcsitemapprovider, asp.net-mvc-sitemap

Currently, I have a `Controller` with an `Index()` action method that needs authorization:

```
public partial class CustomerController : BaseDocumentStoreController
{
    [Authorize(Roles = AccountController.Administrator)]
    public virtual ViewResult Index()
    {
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

With this in place, the respective node in the `Mvc.sitemap` won't show in the breadcrumbs:

```
<mvcSiteMapNode     title="Customer"         controller="Customer" action="Index"
                    resourceKey="Customers"  clickable="true" >

    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Customer Add"     controller="Customer" action="Add"
                    resourceKey="Add"  />
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Customer Create"  controller="Customer" action="Create"
                    resourceKey="Add" />
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Customer Edit"    controller="Customer" action="Edit"
                    resourceKey="Edit" />
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Customer Update"  controller="Customer" action="Update"
                    resourceKey="Edit" />
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Customer Delete"  controller="Customer" action="Delete"
                    resourceKey="Delete" />
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Customer Details" controller="Customer" action="Details"
                    resourceKey="Details" />
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Customer Search"  controller="Customer" action="Search"
                    resourceKey="Search" />

</mvcSiteMapNode>
```

What I want is to show this node anyway...

Let's say the user is not authenticated. So I want the breadcrumbs to show this:

```
Home > Customers > Add
```

Currently it only shows:

```
Add
```

If the user clicks the **Customers** node he'll be redirected to the login view... OK, that's fine!

I tried to implement my own `SiteMapVisibilityProvider` following [these steps](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Advanced-Node-Visibility):

```
public class SiteMapVisibilityProvider : ISiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider
{
   ...
}
```

While debugging I could only see the nodes bellow the Index node, that is, in my current case, only the Add node showed up. The node that represents the Index action method didn't show up in the debugging session.

Is there any way of achieving what I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem most likely lies in the `DefaultAclModule`, which hides all nodes inaccessible to the current user. If you don't want that functionality it can be disabled by setting `securitytrimming` to false, in the sitemap provider in web.config.

You could also change the functionality by implementing a custom `AclModule`.

Comment: You're absolutely right! Tried setting    `securityTrimmingEnabled="false"` in web.config and it works great! After reading this blog post by Maarten (MvcSiteMapProvider creator): http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2008/08/29/Building-an-ASPNET-MVC-sitemap-provider-with-security-trimming.aspx I now understand how the `Authorize`attribute works with a `MvcSiteMapNode` node. The concept I didn't know about was the security trimming you mention in your answer. Thank you very much mate... :)

Comment: By the way: I saw your excellent series of posts called Inside the MvcSiteMapProvider. Really useful man... This one just talk about the AclModule you mention: http://xharze.blogspot.com.br/2012/04/inside-mvcsitemapprovider-part-4.html Great work and keep it up.